# Rails + processing.js - where to put .pde files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, processing, asset-pipeline

I am using Rails 3.2 with asset pipeline. I am trying to add some processing.js to the app, the processing.js file is found fine, but the .pde file gives the error:

```
Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to load pjs sketch files: graphBuilder.pde ==> Invalid XHR status 404
```

The folder structure is usual:

RailsApp/app/assets/javascripts/pjs/graphBuilder.pde
                                    processing.js

so I of course have an pjs.js file with

```
//*= require_self
// *= require_tree ./pjs
```

How do I make Rails see graphBuilder.pde??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to change the path to the graphBuilder.pde in Processing.js to `/assets/pjs/graphBuilder.pde` if I understand correctly.

Comment: hmm.. I have hard time finding where processing.js references the .pde location.. ?

Comment: Do you have a `<canvas data-processing-sources="graphBuilder.pde"></canvas>` somewhere? If so, change the path to the one above.

Comment: wow thanks a lot! was doing that but forgot the / before "/assets/"